# "Recommended reading" material isn't linked in "traditional view"

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, traditional-view

Observe...

#### Old CV:

[image: books are linked]

#### New Developer Story, "Story view":

[image: books are still linked]

#### New Developer Story, "Traditional view":

[image: no links.]

Comment: Y U NO use free hand circle in the third example?  Did you run out?

Comment: Yes. As you can see by the color, my marker was nearly out of ink by the last example. I should've written smaller.

Comment: That's ludicrous! I'm looking into it

Comment: I have spun the Wheel of Blame several times, but it keeps telling me it's your fault for some reason.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that Forth is an OS as well as a language.

Comment: I didn't name the book, @Petah - credit Brodie!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oops! Yes, I completely forgot to add the links on the traditional view. This has now been fixed <3